# Energy of a signal simplification

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I'm learning about signals from the textbook *Signals and Systems Second Edition*, by Oppenheim and Willsky in order to learn more about Fourier Analysis and I'm having difficulty with the Energy equation that I found for a complex periodic signal. For this type of signal, we have the following basic form for the energy of the signal over 1 period:

$$E_{period} = \int_{0}^{T_0} |e^{j\omega_0t}|^2dt$$

which then simplifies to just:

$$E_{period} = \int_{0}^{T_0} 1 \cdot dt$$

I'm assuming that the text is saying $e^{j\omega_0t} = e^{j\omega_0T} = 1$ but I don't understand how it arrives to this conclusion. Based on earlier information in the text, I know that for any complex periodic signal:

$$x(t) = e^{i\omega_0t} = e^{i\omega_0(t+T)}$$

and this equation is used to obtain :

$$x(t) = e^{i\omega_0t} = e^{i\omega_0t}e^{i\omega_0T} \Rightarrow e^{i\omega_0T} = 1$$

However, I do not see how this can also be used to deduce that $e^{j\omega_0t}=1$ as well. So, could someone please help clear up why the signal inside the integral simplifies to 1?

Note: at this point in the book, it is just going over the different types of signals and has not yet touched Fourier Analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parseval's theorem for the Fourier Transform is defined as follows:
$$E_x = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|x(t)|^2 dt = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|X(\omega)|^2 d\omega $$

To answer your equation, please take note of your notation.
Given the complex signal:
$$ x(t) = e^{j\omega_0 t} $$
This implies:
$$ |x(t)| = |e^{j\omega_0 t}| = 1 $$
Comments: Recall the $|\cdot|$ function means the length of the complex number. $e^{j\omega_0 t}$ is a unit circle in the complex plane, with the angular frequency of $\omega_0$. Even if the complex signal is periodic over $T$, i.e. $e^{j\omega_0 (t+T)}$, the length remains the same, i.e. $|e^{j\omega_0 t}|=|e^{j\omega_0 (t+T)}|=1$. Hope it clears your doubts.